Query shows only one result, 4 expected
I have a table with four values ​​that I would like to read and then process further within a PHP script.
MariaDB [mydbase]> select Pet from PETS; 
 +--------+
 | Pet    | 
 +--------+
 | Dog    |
 | Cat    |
 | Mouse  |
 | Badger |
 +--------+ 
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)

Unfortunately, only the first entry is displayed.
For debugging purpose I am using a foreach loop as well as print_r() with no difference...
❯ php queryarray.php
Dog
Array
(
    [0] => Dog
)

This is my PHP Script
<?php

require_once ('./php/myfunctions.php'); // for function: mydbconnect() and the DB credentials
$mysqli = mydbconnect();

$query = 'select Pet from PETS;';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$queryarray = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

foreach ($queryarray as $rowdb) {
  echo $rowdb."\n";
}

print_r($queryarray);
?>

The mydbconnect function is:
<?php
  function mydbconnect () {
    require_once ('../phpconfig.local/phpcreds.php'); // Database credentials
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); // Alle fehlermeldungen an
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    // Testen ob die Verbung zur DB steht
    if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
      exit();
    }
    return $mysqli;
  }
?>

I'm either blind, stupid or probably both, but I can't solve it...
When doing it by hand and writing the values directly into an array to read it out, I get the expected result...
<?php 
  $manualarray = array('Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse', 'Badger');
  foreach ($manualarray as $rowm) { 
    echo $rowm."\n";
  }
  print_r($manualarray); 
?> 

Output:
> php manualarray.php 
Dog 
Cat 
Mouse 
Badger 
Array
(
    [0] => Dog
    [1] => Cat
    [2] => Mouse
    [3] => Badger
)


fetch_array() just fetches one row of results. You're confusing it with fetch_all().
